# Div the same width as other div but responsive

Tags: html, css

I want to stretch my img inside a div to the same width as another div which is higher up in the hierarchy.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
         <img></img>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The img should have the same width as the most upper div (but this div does not fit the whole screen). I know that it's possible to do with absolute position but I want it responsive. It's not possible to move the img up because that is php generated.

Comment: Can you please provide some more codes as it's hard to determine what is going on with the above html. It would be helpful if you can provide the `css` and the code that generates the image (js/php/whatever is generating it)

Comment: Perhaps you could put some class on the DIVs which should have the same width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always make the div you want to resize the image to `relative positioned` and make the image `absolute positioned`...

```css
.biggest {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 2px red;
}
div {
  width: 50%;
  border: solid 2px blue;
  height: 100px;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="biggest">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```